# how to make a webservice (WSDL) which can only be used from my e.g. android app?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

i have a question about a .net WSDL webservice.

i want to make a android app which access the webservice, but i dont want to make a public webservice. the webservice should only be accessable by the application so no other user who know the url can access it.

are there any methods to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a 100% safe method to do this. I can suggest generating and sending a key with each request. Normally only the application code would be able to generate a valid key that would be recognized by the web service. You can also use HTTPS on top of that for added privacy against sniffers.

Comment: no, I don't do mobile development - this is just an idea on top of my head